# Xamarin application does not work in ad-hoc mode

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to xamarin. I have developed the app which  has locally embedded website (in application itself) which loads in webpart. This angular website  is also hosted on server when user is connected to internet it pull the data from server whereas when user is offline the. It shows the data from local DB in app. If I open the website in safari browser from same device then it loads the website but same is not working from app.I am building the app in ad-hoc mode. Any idea what can be wrong.

Comment: Webview inside an ios application is a little different than Safari browser. Maybe you should set some setting for the webview.

Comment: Is your website started with `http` or `https`? Maybe you need config [Configuring ATS Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/ats#configuring-ats-options) in the `info.plist` in iOS project.